# Get Coco Class files programmatically

Tags: objective-c

Using the `objc/runtime.h` we can create classes at runtime. How to export the `.h` and `.m` files from that class which is created at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `.h` is conceptually possible, but you'd need to write the code yourself to do it (using ObjC runtime calls to inspect the class and then write the file by hand). I don't know of anyone who has written this code already, but writing it would likely be an excellent introduction to the ObjC runtime functions. Note that the `.h` probably wouldn't be very friendly. For example, all object types in method signatures will be `id`. So it's kind of useable, but I can't think of a lot of ways I'd want to.

Creating a `.m` here doesn't make a lot of sense. The implementation of a runtime-generated class is going to be a bunch of IMP pointers to existing functions (which are themselves already compiled code). I don't know what you'd expect to be in the `.m`. In principle you could scan the executable to work out the names of the functions, and then write out a `.m` that looked something like:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    SomeMethod_IMP()
}
```

This would probably get pretty complicated, and I can imagine several corner cases that would bite you in the general case.

This generally isn't how dynamically-generated classes are used, though, in the fairly rare cases that they are used. They're ubiquitous in KVO (but you'd never want a `.h` from that), and other uses of them are kind of similar: they usually are some magical subclass of an existing interface, so you never interact with them directly (and they almost always have an identical API to their superclass). What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

To get the implementation, you'd have to find or write a tool to translate assembly back in to Objective-C.

For just generating a header (interface), there are tools available.  Use Google.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot just tell the Objective-C runtime to create a new class from the .h and .m files because it takes a compiler. You need to hard-code the creation inside your project.

1. Create a subclass with objc_allocateClassPair
2. Add methods with class_addMethod (and properties with class_addProperty...)

Then you can use the new class.